# NFS instead of HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

HDFS is the heart of Hadoop, I get that. But what if I don't want to store my data on HDFS. Instead, I want to analyze and run Hadoop jobs on data stored on a remote server accessible via the NFS protocol? How do I do that?

For example, I want to run Teragen using the data on the NFS server like below:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar teragen 1000000000 nfs://IP/some/path
```

I am just looking for ideas on how to do this and I do understand the repercussions of all this (HDFS vs NFS). So, while I appreciate anyone telling me that it's a bad idea, I still want to do it for some experiment that I am trying.

I can maybe code something to make this happen but any pointers where I need to start will be helpful and much appreciated. I also don't want to reinvent the wheel. So, if something like this already exists that I am unaware of, please do comment and let me know. Anything that I build will be made open-source so that others can benefit as well.

Comment: You can always do the reverse and create an NFS gateway for HDFS.

Comment: NFS gateway for HDFS already exists (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html) and is not what I am talking about. All that the NFS gateway does is "allows HDFS to be mounted as part of the client’s local file system". This is very different from what I am asking where you can run Hadoop jobs on data stored on a remote NFS server, nothing to do with HDFS.

Comment: You can always run your app in YARN local mode and have your data paths point to a NFS mounted partition.  I know this should work on a single node but you'd have to see if you can do this on a cluster running only YARN without HDFS.  Of course, your NFS mounts need to be symmetric on all your cluster hosts.

Comment: "NFS mounted partition" breaks what I am trying to do. Please read my question and description again. If I mount NFS partitions then that would be exactly the same as HDFS where the NFS volumes would just look like local volumes to Hadoop. What I am looking for is different where HDFS doesn't come into the picture and so doesn't namenode (or maybe it can, not sure how it would work without data being stored on HDFS). Data is read and written to the remote NFS server using some NFS client. That's where I need some pointers on how to go about doing that. Hopefully, this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know this site:
https://blog.netapp.com/blogs/run-big-data-analytics-natively-on-nfs-data/

It looks like you can exchange HDFS with NFS at the bottom, while at a higher abstraction layer everything works as before as MapReduce/YARN will take care of everything for you.

I can not tell anything about whether or not this works, as we are currently preparing to set up such a "native NFS hadoop". I will come back to you with more details in some months.